# How do I partition my Windows hard drive?

Tags: installation, windows, partitioning

I want to partition the hard drive on my Windows computer and run Ubuntu under that partition. How can I go about doing this?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to install Ubuntu on a Windows computer, you will need to create an individual partition for Ubuntu. When you load your live CD, there will be choices that you can chose when it comes to partitioning your Hard drive, you will need to shrink you windows partition in order to created un-allocated space. Its very easy to do, the GUI in the installer package essentially walks you through every step. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

you can do this when you install Ubuntu, there will come a question saying something like: "do you want to eraze your hard drive or make a partition". it's quite easy, just follow the instructions in the installation. Good luck.